# IHttpHandler ProcessRequest call twice only by Safari

Tags: asp.net, safari, http-headers, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a web-app that allows previewing of uploaded media content (images, MP3s, swf files, and videos). All uploaded videos correctly encoded and played using an HTML5 video tag.

```
strHTML += '<video id="' + ObjectID + '" controls preload="auto" width="' + WIDTH + '" height="' + HEIGHT + '">' +
            '<source src="' + URL + '" type="video/mp4" />' +
            '</video>';
```

I have a source handler that maps the above URL into the correct directory on the server.

```
 public class SrcUrlHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
 {
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {
        //if previewing videos
        string filename = string.IsNullOrEmpty(spot.MEDIA_FILE) ? string.Empty : spot.MEDIA_FILE.Trim();
        string fileDir = tmpl.GetClientContentDirectory((int)clientId, ClientContentDirectory.Working);
        string fullName = fileDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "standardized_spid_" + spot.SPOT_ID + ".mp4";

        if (!File.Exists(fullName))
            return;

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fullName);
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
        context.Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
        context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
     }
 }
```

This works on FF, IE, Chorme in Windows and Chrome in OSX. However this fails with Safari on OSX. For some reason Safari makes three http requests. ProcessRequest gets called twice and fails at the third request. (Disregard the first row in the image below.)

[image: Safari makes three requests while every other browser is able to retrieve the video from the first request.]
The first request is from the actual browser.
[image: This first request makes sense. It is the browser trying to get the data]
The second request from user agent AppleCoreMedia.
[image: Second request]
The third from Quicktime.
[image: Third request]

Why is this happening? The only similar problem I found was at http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternetExplorerAndTheMagicOfMicrosoftKBArticleQ293792.aspx and that isn't very relevant. The preview works for all other media types (swf, png, jpg) on safari, it does not make multiple requests. The final 302 response code does not make sense as the video location never changes. Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally solved the problem. Safari requires video streaming to use the 206 Partial Content header. I implemented the code I found at http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/easy-handling-of-http-range-requests-in-asp-net/ and everything work!